# Why do I get "!Missing $ inserted" error when I use math mode inside \fbox{} command?

Tags: errors, fbox

I wanted to create a box around of the theory which I'm going to present so I typed the following code:

```
\fbox{\textbf{ΘΕΩΡΙΑ} $$a^x= \theta \iff x=log_\alpha \theta$$
$$log_\alpha 1=0$$ $$log_\alpha \alpha=1$$}
```

(I want to have a title for the theory so I used "\textbf{}" and I used double dollars because I want each formula to have it's own line)
What do I do wrong? How to type it properly?

Comment: also `log` should be `\log` never use math italic for words

Answer (score 3):

`$$` should never be used in latex, but `\fbox` is like `\mbox` (and the `\hbox` primitive) and makes a horizontal box that can not have vertical material such as display math or `\vspace`.  `$$`  in this context is the same as `$ $` and makes an empty inline math list, it does not start display math.

`\fbox{\parbox{3cm}{xxx\[x^2\]yyy}}`

will box a paragraph including display math